# Run script as root after autologin in X

Tags: login, root, x-server, slim

I've got a public PC on which there are:

- 1 big screen
- 1 touchscreen, the user can touch it and navigate through a website
- the website is in fullscreen, right click is disabled and the keyboard that appears doesn't have keys like Alt, F1, etc..

At startup, I would like to check if every components plugged to the PC work and if it's the case, I'd like to run these two windows on each screen.

I didn't find any solution to start both instances of chromium in fullscreen to 2 different screens, so I started firefox for the big screen and chromium for the touchscreen.

These instances of chromium and firefox are running at startup, (by the user which is -automatically- connected to the session) by adding a custom file in the .config/autostart folder.

I'm running Debian 7.9. I use slim as display manager. Yes i use autologin, so there are no "login screen". I need root access for listing and opening devices. I need to check their presence and test them before I can open chromium and firefox windows. I would like the script to be ran after the autologin.

---

Now, I tried to put the script to check if the components work in /etc/rc.local, but this file runs at runlevel 2, so I can't interact with X server by opening windows, etc.

My question is: Do I have to wait runlevel 4 (or 5) to run a script as root or there is another better solution ? I feel what I do is just a dirty DIY...

Comment: What distribution are you running? What display manager (the GUI program where the user types their name and password) are you running, if any? Are you using autologin? Do you actually want to run the script when the X server starts, or after login? What do you want to run that requires being root?

Comment: I'm running Debian 7.9. I use slim as display manager. Yes i use autologin, so there are no "login screen".
I need root access for listing and opening devices. I need to check their presence and test them before I can open chromium and firefox windows. I would like the script to be ran after the autologin.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` and runlevels won't help you if you need something after X has started. You need something in the SLiM configuration, which I'm not familiar with. That, or call sudo from a script in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`, but it's more difficult to get the security right this way.